# Two columns not displaying correctly in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display two columns side by side (the one on the left has 4 items and the one on the right has 3, totalling 7 items altogether) and I have:

```css
#wrap{
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  column-count: 2;
}
#left_col {
   float:left;
   width:200px;
}
#right_col{
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left_col">
    <a href="number1.php"><img src="number1.png"alt="number1" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>num1</a>
    <a href="number2.php"><img src="number2.png"alt="number2" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>num2</a>
    <a href="number3.php"><img src="number3.png"alt="number3" border="0" align="top" height="75" width="65"/>num3</a>
    <a href="number4.php"><img src="number4.png"alt="number4" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>num4</a>
  </div>
  <div id="right_col">
    <a href="num1.php"><img src="num1.png"alt="num1" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>number1</a>
    <a href="num2.php"><img src="num2.png"alt="num2" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>number2</a>
    <a href="num3.php"><img src="num3.png"alt="num3" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>number3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my problem is that when I run it, the links/images/text in the `left_col` doesn't seem to be displayed as one item on each row like in the `right_col` and it's not showing the text together as it seems to be on the line below it.

Comment: Without a [mcve] I don't see how we can help except to say that 75+75+65+75 is more than 200

Comment: An example in jsfiddle (or like) would be helpful.

Comment: Inside wrap add property display:inline-block;

Comment: `column-count` is a property to manage `CSS columns`, if you use float don't use columns and viceversa.

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6e3kxk5/2/)

Comment: You are relying on the computed width of the img + label to wrap at the correct place, but your labels are different lengths. You could force the wrap with a BR, or make your labels all the same length, or set your anchor tags to display as blocks or....

Comment: Both columns are actually the same. The reason why the left one seems broken is because each item is shorter in width compared to the ones in the right div (because of different texts) and so the 2nd image fits on the first row, whereas in the right div it doesn't and thus jumps down to the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display:block` on the `a` tag:

```css
#wrap{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#left_col {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
}
#right_col{
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left_col">
    <a href="number1.php"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/65/technics/1" alt="number1" height="65" width="75"/> Number 1</a>
    <a href="number2.php"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/65/technics/2" alt="number2" height="65" width="75"/> Number 2</a>
    <a href="number3.php"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/65/75/technics/3" alt="number3" height="75" width="65"/> Number 3</a>
    <a href="number4.php"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/65/technics/4" alt="number4" height="65" width="75"/> Number 4</a>
  </div>
  <div id="right_col">
    <a href="num1.php"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/65/technics/5" alt="num1" height="65" width="75"/> Number 1</a>
    <a href="num2.php"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/65/technics/6" alt="num2" height="65" width="75"/> Number 2</a>
    <a href="num3.php"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/65/technics/7" alt="num3" height="65" width="75"/> Number 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Though, ideally you should do this using lists.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrap{
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  column-count: 2;
}
#left_col {
   float:left;
   width:200px;
}
#left_col a {
   display: block;
}
#right_col{
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left_col">
    <a href="number1.php"><img src="number1.png"alt="number1" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>num1</a>
    <a href="number2.php"><img src="number2.png"alt="number2" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>num2</a>
    <a href="number3.php"><img src="number3.png"alt="number3" border="0" align="top" height="75" width="65"/>num3</a>
    <a href="number4.php"><img src="number4.png"alt="number4" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>num4</a>
  </div>
  <div id="right_col">
    <a href="num1.php"><img src="num1.png"alt="num1" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>number1</a>
    <a href="num2.php"><img src="num2.png"alt="num2" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>number2</a>
    <a href="num3.php"><img src="num3.png"alt="num3" border="0" align="top" height="65" width="75"/>number3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put **150 px** for the `width` of your columns:

```
#wrap{
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  column-count: 2;
}
#left_col {
   float:left;
   width:150px;
}
#right_col{
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
}
```